# Cannot drag and drop Annotation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, acceleo, eclipse-sirius

i am working with eclipse modelling tool 2020, i did not change anything in the original IFML source but when i try to drag and drop Annotation, it cannot be instantiated inside other element, can only be instantiated outside of the component when the intended behavior of annotation, it can be attached to whatever component, how can i fix this?
I have already try to open the plugin editor, i try to look for solution on other platform, but i haven't found any meaningful solution[image: the file structure and the annotation code]

Comment: Your Eclipse is very, very old. Please make sure Eclipse and Sirius (which is the modelling tool you use) is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're supposed to create an Annotation and then add an edge between the Annotation and whatever element it pertains to.